# Custom icons reapearing on Firefox 29

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I've been using [Readability's Firefox add-on](https://readability.com/apps) for some time, but since Firefox 29 I can't set it to display a single icon on the browser bar: I use Firefox's preferences to customize the bar, but when I restart the browser, it will display all three icons again:

[image]

I have already contacted the app's support, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a reply from their support, stating:

> unfortunately we have a bug with the latest firefox (29+) versions
>   which wont save user preferences. If you set your buttons up the way
>   you want them, then visit
>
> about:config and set extensions.readability.first_run_complete to true
>
> it should save your buttons the way they are

I tested and it works.